# homebrew check binary package availability

Tags: homebrew

Is there a `brew` command to check if the formula I want to install is available as binary or I have to install it from source.

As corollary, if I need to install a particular formula by recompiling it with `brew install --build-from-source XXXX` all the packages on which that particular formula depend will be rebuilt from source too?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`brew info <formula>` will tell you if a given formula is bottled (= compiled) for your system, e.g.:

```
$ brew info postgresql | head -n 1
postgresql: stable 9.5.1 (bottled)
```

You can get more info by using `--json=v1`:

```
# bottled formula
$ brew info --json=v1 postgresql | jq '.[0].bottle'
{
  "stable": {
    "revision": 0,
    ...
  }
}

# non-bottled formula
$ brew info --json=v1 docker-machine-nfs | jq '.[0].bottle'
{}
```

---

> if I need to install a particular formula by recompiling it with `brew install --build-from-source XXXX` all the packages on which that particular formula depend will be rebuilt from source too?

Only the dependencies you don’t already have will be built from source.

Comment: Oh thanks, so if I want to recompile a formula XXX, it's better to start by installing the bottled binary (which will install all binary dependencies) then uninstall XXX and re-install from source, right?

Comment: Use `brew install --build-bottle --only-dependencies XXX && brew install -s XXX`. The first command installs all the dependencies (`--build-bottle` forces it to install the build deps) and the second installs the formula from source (`-s` is short for `--build-from-source`). Use `brew reinstall -s XXX` to reinstall from source if it’s already installed.